# How to play video on lockscreen like Live Wallpapers app?

Tags: ios, video, background

[Live Wallpapers app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/live-wallpapers/id475230306?mt=8) can play video on lockscreen. How does it do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the reviews, the answer appears to be "badly, if at all". One reviewer notes succinctly:

> The animation doesn't stay up unless the app is open...

My first guess would be that it generates a sequence of images and cycles the lockscreen image through each of them.

Comment: This app plays video on lockscreen while it is in foreground and when it is suspended (appears in multitasking bar).

Comment: How can I "cycles the lockscreen image through each of them" from my app?